# How can I quickly know the colors used in a web image?

Tags: color, software-recommendation, tools, rgb, latex

Supposing that I have the following table,

[image]

Is there a fast method (with external tools with the web: for example **ColorZilla**, browser extension) to recognize the color in RGB (or CMYK) without to install any software?

For me it is important to know because I use `LaTeX` for my important document.

Which software supports the function of identifying the color used in a given image?

Comment: Maybe this isn't for you, but on Mac I'd recommend [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/) or [Sip](https://sipapp.io/). They are essentially OS wide color pickers. — I like Color Snapper, because it has [this zoom toggle, which zooms in really close when you hold down `Ctrl`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx9pj.gif). It's way nicer than increasing and decreasing the zoom level using 2 different shortcuts, which is what you gotta do in Sip. Sip recently had a big update, so maybe they added that. Who knows... I don't.

Comment: @Joonas Very good. Can you delete your comment and give me a complete answer adding also the screenshots? I like give all user also a vote.

Comment: I didn't think it fit here mainly cause you didn't want to install any applications, but I guess it can still help other people. I'll post it as an answer, but I'll have to do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a search for Color Picker. You find several tools like this:

[image]

It's here: https://imagecolorpicker.com/en

If you can run legacy Photoshop, you can as well do PrntScrn to copy an image to the clipboard, then open a new image in PS, paste and check the colors with the picker.

Answer (score 3):

If an image is in a web browser, it is rendered as RGB, so basic color pickup will work. Use Colorzilla or any other color pickup tool (browser based or local installation doesn't matter).
CMYK image have no use of values without knowledge what color profile is used, so no simple solution is possible. Mozilla have several Color Management solutions built in in testing versions, but they are still experimental, so I would never rely on them.

Comment: Meanwhile I thank you and in the same way as I work in TeX.SE. I always vote in favor of any answer I am given, as it is correct on my part, consider the time taken by a user to provide an answer. Do you know any other color pickup tools? I currently have an old pc and would not like to create problems. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**I got 2 application suggestions for Mac:**

- [ColorSnapper](https://colorsnapper.com/) ~$9

  - Latest update [November 29, 2019](https://colorsnapper.com/changelog/)
- [Sip Color Picker](https://sipapp.io/) ~$10

  - Latest update [November 21, 2019](https://sipapp.io/updates/)

**They are OS wide color pickers so they can be used to pick colors from anything you see in your screen without having to feed it an image or take a screenshot first or something.**

I own both and I've used them quite a lot, but to me Color Snapper has one killer feature: [A zoom toggle that zooms in really close when you hold down Ctrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx9pj.gif). This is amazing because you can zero in on top of the area with lesser zoom super easily and then with one single modifier key zoom in close enough to differentiate pixels and the cursor will move slower too. Additionally, both of these applications have shortcuts for resizing and zooming the magnifying glass once it's activated, but they take more effort to use. I've tried to jump over to using SIP a few times, but I always end up missing the toggle zoom and go back to Color Snapper.

I do also like that with Color Snapper you pick the color and then it suggests the different output formats, whereas with Sip, you gotta choose the format first and then pick the color. It's not a big deal though... If you pick a color in the wrong format, you can change the format and copy the color to your clipboard again from the color history.

SIP has CMYK color output, and Color Snapper doesn't. They both have trials.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need *any* external tools if you are using a browser. You can just use the built-in colour picker of the development tools. I'll give an example for Chrome, but it's basically the same for every browser.

1. Right-click and choose 'Inspect element' or <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. In element.style, type a property with a color, e.g. `color: red`
3. Click the colored square in front of the colour name
4. Make sure the Color picker is toggled on
5. Pick the colour you want, you can even switch between HEX, RGBA and HSLA

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much to have know another method. I'm sorry for a strange downvote for my question.